# Unable to start httpd service in CentOS7

Tags: apache, centos, centos7

I have installed httpd service in CentOS7 by following the commands.

```
sudo yum install epel-release -y
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install httpd -y
```

I am facing

```
Failed to start httpd.service: Activation of org.freedesktop.systemd1 timed out
See system logs and 'systemctl status httpd.service' for details.
```

when trying to start the service using `sudo systemctl start httpd.service`. I have googled alot but unable to find the root cause for this issue. Kindly help on what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this answer 7 months late to help you. But for anyone reading this in the future, check the log messages and try to make sense of it.

Most often the problem is that port 80 is not free and some other process is using it. You can check all the processes that are being run and the ports being used by using the "lsof" command.